# Change file name in GIT

Tags: git, bash, shell

I'm working on a pre-receive hook. I want all the files to be named in UPPER CASE. If a file doesn't respect this condition we should stop the push and ask the user to change the file name. I tried

```
if [[ "$fileName" =~ [a-z] ]]; then
  echo -e "file should be in upper Case" >&2
  exit 1;
fi
```

The push is stopped after a user changes the filename with

```
git mv -f tes TES
```

and I always get the error that the file is lowercase. Should I delete the file from the last commit and commit again with new name?

Comment: Some ideas: Don't post merely a fragment of code that we can't interpret out of context; code to reproduce a problem should be minimal but also *complete*. Post actual and expected results instead of "it doesn't work".  (Note that "results" includes actual copies of any output - not a description of the output - especially any error messages.)

Comment: Are you asking if you have to commit again, with the new fixed file name? Yes

Comment: yes and i should i delete the old name from the last commit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the hook is working.  However, that doesn't remove the commit with the lowercase filename from the history of the local repo's ref.

If the user is just pushing a single commit, then they can fix the filenames and then

```
git commit --amend
```

More commonly, a user might push multiple commits at once.  Assuming your hook checks all commits (if not, lowercase names will leak in to your history over time), the user will have to fix the entire history before pushing.  This can be done with `git filter-branch`.  To clean up a branch called `the_branch` so it can be pushed:

- Write a script that renames any file in the working tree to all-uppercase.  You can call it whatever, but for discussion let's say `ucfn.sh`
- Use the script as a tree filter

So

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter=ucfn.sh -- the_branch
```

Or maybe

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter=ucfn.sh -- origin/the_branch..the_branch
```

(You can make this run faster (if there are lots of new commits, or if the work tree is quite large) by switching to an `index-filter`, but the script is harder to write because you have no work tree in an `index-filter`.)

The best thing is to help your users avoid this condition, by providing them with a pre-commit hook that checks whether the push will be accepted, and rejects the commit otherwise.  Like any local hook, they'd have to choose to set it up and you can't force them to use it - so you still need the post-receive hook - but this can stop your users from getting into a corner where they have a huge clean-up before they can push.

Comment: Nicely done, i have  a not working case if the file is named TEST.txt when changing it to TEST.TXT and git commit --amend  the TEST.txt version isn't deleted

Comment: Depending on OS and config settings, control of filename case can get a little flaky, because your filesystem either does or doesn't consider `foo.txt` and `FOO.TXT` to be different files, and git either does or doesn't think that your filesystem considers `foo.txt` and `FOO.TXT` to be different files.  The `core.ignoreCase` configuration value may be of some help here.